# Searchview in recyclerview duplicates the data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

A search view is implemented in action bar, the search works fine, but for example,
If user search for two characters **pa**, my list contains 2 data related to the related to **pa** i.e., pack1,pack2 then data loads in the recycler view. now if user enter another character **l**, to the previous characters pa, now my search view has **pal** , but array list doesn't match with the search, the list doesn't contain any item with pal. i.e., now the recycler view is empty. now, if I clear the character **l**, the list gets reloaded with data pack1, pack2, but result loads 2 times i.e., instead of showing 2 items in recyclerview, it shows 4 items in total.
It is duplicating the items, when the search is cleared.

searchview

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_order, menu);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                mOrderAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if(newText.length()==0){
                    getData();
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                }
                mOrderAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true ;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Filter code

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String charString = constraint.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()||charString.length()==0) {
                    mListFilter = mOrderArrayList;
                } else {
                    List<Order> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<Order> templist=new ArrayList<Order>();
                    for (Order ord : mOrderArrayList) {
                        if (ord.getOs_OrderNo().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())
                                || ord.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(ord);
                            templist.addAll(mListFilter);
                        }
                    }
                    mOrderArrayList.removeAll(templist);
                    mOrderArrayList.addAll(filteredList);
                    mListFilter = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mListFilter;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mListFilter = (ArrayList<Order>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Adapter code

```
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Order> mListFilter,mOrderArrayList;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Resources r;


    public OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Order> orderList) {
        mContext = context;
        mListFilter = orderList;
        mOrderArrayList = orderList;
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        r = context.getResources();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView orderNoView, itemNameView, qtyView, statusView, companyNameView;
        private Order currentItem;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            orderNoView = view.findViewById(R.id.orderNo);
            itemNameView = view.findViewById(R.id.item);
            qtyView = view.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            statusView = view.findViewById(R.id.status);
            companyNameView = view.findViewById(R.id.company);

        }

        void bind (Order om) {  //<--bind method allows the ViewHolder to bind to the data it is displaying
            orderNoView.setText(om.getOs_OrderNo());
            itemNameView.setText(String.valueOf(om.getItemName()));
            qtyView.setText("Qty - " + String.valueOf(om.getOs_Qty()));
            statusView.setText(om.getStatusName());

            if (sharedPreferences.getString(r.getString(R.string.key_CompanyInUser), "").equals("0")){
                companyNameView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                companyNameView.setText(om.getCustomerName());
            }
            currentItem = om; //<-- keep a reference to the current item
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_order, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Order item =  mListFilter.get(position);
        holder.bind(item);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListFilter.size();
    }


    @Override

    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return  position;

    }
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String charString = constraint.toString();
            List<Order> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (charString.isEmpty()||charString.length()==0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mOrderArrayList);
            } else {
                for (Order ord : mOrderArrayList) {
                    if (ord.getOs_OrderNo().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())
                            || ord.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(ord);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mListFilter = (ArrayList<Order>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

}
```

Clicklistener code

```
  brandView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), brandView,
                new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                        isRefreshData = true;
                        startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ViewOrderDetails.class).putExtra("Key-Intent-OrderNo",mOrderArrayList.get(position).getOs_OrderNo()).putExtra("Key-Intent-BrandName",mOrderArrayList.get(position).getos_BrandName()));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                    }
                }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using `addAll` inside a loop in `#performFiltering` . Also why you have two local list for filtering? Check the method below it should work . i have removed the extra code and code which is causing the issue .

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String charString = constraint.toString();
            List<Order> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (charString.isEmpty()||charString.length()==0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mOrderArrayList);
            } else {
                for (Order ord : mOrderArrayList) {
                    if (ord.getOs_OrderNo().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())
                            || ord.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(ord);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mListFilter = (ArrayList<Order>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. the solution works. but one more issue came. now if i enter another character like pac, after clearing this duplication happens agian. two locallist was created when i faced a similar duplication issue

Comment: i have added sir

Comment: Code seems fine to me . Try debugging

Comment: ok thank you. temp list was added in code because after filtering when clicking on the filtered item other item opens i.e. it opens item from main list not filtered list. in short after filtering it takes position of main list not filtered list. how can i solve this by the code now

Comment: I don't see click listener in your code . how are you adding click listener update the code in question . You have to use mListFilter to get the clicked item

Comment: I'm calling a new activity on touchlistener in recycler view code added. this code is in activity. i have added the code

Comment: Set listener on view inside adapter do not use on touch listener . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick